# interpretation of SVD for text mining topic analysis

Tags: nlp, text-mining, svd, topic-modeling, latent-semantic-indexing

**Background**

I'm learning about text mining by building my own text mining toolkit from scratch - the best way to learn!

**SVD**

The Singular Value Decomposition is often cited as a good way to:

- Visualise high dimensional data (word-document matrix) in 2d/3d
- Extract key topics by reducing dimensions

I've spent about a month learning about the SVD .. I must admit much of the online tutorials, papers, university lecture slides, .. and even proper printed textbooks are not that easy to digest.

Here's my understanding so far: [SVD demystified (blog)](http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2017/02/singular-value-decomposition-demystified.html)

I think I have understood the following:

- Any (real) matrix can be decomposed uniquely into 3 multiplied
  matrices using SVD, A=U⋅S⋅V^T
- S is a diagonal matrix of singular values, in descending order of magnitude
- U and V^T are matrices of orthonormal vectors

I understand that we can reduce the dimensions by filtering out less significant information by zero-ing the smaller elements of S, and reconstructing the original data. If I wanted to reduce dimensions to 2, I'd only keep the 2 top-left-most elements of the diagonal S to form a new matrix S'

**My Problem**

To see the documents projected onto the reduced dimension space, I've seen people use S'⋅V^T. Why? What's the interpretation of S'⋅V^T?

Similarly, to see the topics, I've seen people use U⋅S'. Why? What's the interpretation of this?

My limited school maths tells me I should look at these as transformations (rotation, scale) ... but that doesn't help clarify it either.

** Update ** 
I've added an update to my blog explanation at [SVD demystified (blog)](http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2017/02/singular-value-decomposition-demystified.html) which reflects the rationale from one of the textbooks I looked at to explain why S'.V^T is a document view, and why U.S' is a word view. Still not really convinced ...

Comment: This question is better suited for CrossValidated, I think.

Comment: good post, thx.